# What can justify a long running EXPLAIN on query (postgres)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i'm opposed today to a new kind of query optimising problem.

my query is :

```
SELECT *
 FROM sanrss
 LEFT JOIN sanrum  ON sanrum.sanrum___rforefide = sanrss.sanrss___rforefide AND     sanrum.sanrum___rfovsnide = sanrss.sanrss___rfovsnide AND sanrum.sanrum___sanrsside = sanrss.sanrsside
LEFT JOIN sanact  ON sanact.sanact___rforefide = sanrum.sanrum___rforefide AND sanact.sanact___rfovsnide = sanrum.sanrum___rfovsnide AND sanact.sanact___sanrsside = sanrum.sanrum___sanrsside AND sanact.sanact___sanrumide = sanrum.sanrumide AND sanact.sanact___sanrumide   IS NOT NULL AND sanact.sanact___rsanopide='CCAM'
INNER JOIN saneds  ON sanrss.sanrss___rforefide = saneds.saneds___rforefide AND sanrss.sanrss___rfovsnide = saneds.saneds___rfovsnide AND sanrss.sanrss___sanedside = saneds.sanedside
INNER JOIN sandia ON (sandia___rforefide, sandia___rfovsnide, sandia___sanrsside, sandia___sanrumide, sandiasig) = (sanrum___rforefide, sanrum___rfovsnide, sanrum___sanrsside, sanrumide, 1)
INNER JOIN rsaidp  ON saneds.saneds___rforefide = rsaidp.rsaidp___rforefide AND saneds.saneds___rsaidpide = rsaidp.rsaidpide
  WHERE sanrss.sanrss___rforefide =  'CHUL'  AND sanrss.sanrss___rfovsnide =  '201303_prov'  AND sanrss.sanrssdtf >=  '2013-01-01 00:00:00.0'  AND sanrss.sanrssdtf <=  '2013-03-31 23:59:59.999'
  and sanrss.sanrsside = '7801512'
```

This is not really * but like 300 fields that are selected.

It was slow in one of our server but not in the other, so i run an explain on it to determine the execution plan, this one give me a total runtime of 0.5 ms !!!
But the real total working time of explain analyze was like 3.6 seconds.

So i tried to prepare only the request, it's a this point a realize that only the calculation of query plan was the cause of the huge delay.

I tried to switch some session parameter of GEQO (effort 1, effort 10, GEQO desactivation), no effect on the execution time.
After stats calculation on all table of the query, the calculation time dropped to 2.4 seconds.

The strange point is that on a slower server (same CPU and motherboard, but no ssd storage), the exact same query with same parameters took only 15 ms to determine query plan and execute. The main difference between the two servers is the amount of data, there is like twice the data in the one where is the problem in all the tables.

So what should i consider to understand what is slowing my execution plan calculation ?

Comment: there are same PostgreSQL versions? One bug related to performance of EXPLAIN ANALYZE was fixed in last release.

Comment: twice are on 8.4.8 Postgresql Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like we have define a too large global statistics target. This valus is link strongly time necessary to define a query plan.

Lowering the value has resolve our problem.